# In a Logical ER Design, when should a foreign key, also be a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity, entity-relationship

I'm currently working on a DB design assignment based on a research journal/paper database.
The main problem I'm having is deciding whether certain entities have enough unique identifiers (and the right ones) and whether I've got the relationships right.

So for example. Each Research Paper has a unique PaperID (PK). Each Research Paper has a list of Keywords (generally 4-5) that the authors list at the start of the paper.

1. Am I right in assuming this is a one-to-many relationship? - one paper has many keywords, each keyword instance belongs to one paper.
2. Does the Paper PK (PaperID), then become a FK & PK for the keyword table? does this layout support the one-to-many relationship stated above?

e.g.

---

Table - Paper

PK = PaperID

*list of attributes*

---

Table - Keywords

PK, FK = PaperID

keyword

---

So a query to find all papers with a specific keyword (e.g 'Pig), will bring up results similar to:

PaperID | Keyword

1       | 'Pig'

2       | 'Pig'

63      | 'Pig'

---

Is my logic the correct way of thinking about this?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

***EDIT: So it seems most people think this is a many-to-many relationship, and unfortunately the Research papers have many of these relationships (e.g. Research Aim(s), Main topic(s), Sub Topic(s), Research Types, Research Question(s) )

--> So do I have to resolve these by creating Associative Entities for every single one of these?! Surely there must be a better way to resolve these many-to-many's rather than having to create an extra..... 8-10 Associative entities? Supertype/Subtypes?

Thanks again for everyones response. Learning as I go!

Comment: No your paper-keyword-relation is a many-to-many-relation. Each paper can have many keywords. Each keyword can be attached to many papers.

Comment: It seems ok. But in many situations it will be better to use many to many relation. So U will have `Papers`, `Keywords` and `Keywords do Papers` tables.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would have thought that Keyword to Paper would be a many-to-many relationship.  The keyword 'Pig' appears in many papers.  And any one paper could have many keywords.  That way you can cut down on the duplication of text.  (But then again, it's probably quicker to code your way.)
2. If your relationship is one-to-many, then you probably want a Composite key on your Keywords table, so the PK for keyword is formed from the PaperID + Keyword.  Honestly, I woudldn't sweat it - sounds like you just want an Index on the Keywords rather than worrying about having a well formed PK for that table.